# complex number in polar form with 7th root

Tags: calculus, complex-numbers

write $z=(1-\sqrt{3})^7$ in polar form $z=r(\cos\theta + \iota\sin\theta)$

my method was convert it to exponential form as $r=2^7$ and $\theta=-\frac {7\pi}{3}$ but it says i'm wrong. Can someone point out what did I do wrong in this question?

Comment: @ I think you have to convert it into a principal argument, that is, find an equivalent angle between 0 and 2*pi.

Comment: @ Ishraaq Parvez Yes I also tried to write it in -pi/3 in principle argument but it still says wrong. Thanks btw.

Comment: How about 5*pi/3? Can you check if it is correct

Comment: @ Ishraaq Parvez -pi/3 is the correct one. Sorry I forgot to plug negative symbol. Cheers.

Comment: Is there a typo in the problem.  Title specifies complex number.  Should the problem instead be $z = \left(1 - i\sqrt{3}\right)^7$?  If so, the problem becomes trivial.

Answer (score 1):

Since the query has been edited to indicate that the answer has to be in the form $r \left[\cos \theta + i\sin \theta\right]$ which is a complex number, it is reasonable to presume that the intended problem is

$\displaystyle z = \left[1 - i\sqrt{3}\right]^7
= \left\{2 \times \left[\cos (-\pi/3) + i\sin(-\pi/3)\right]\right\}^7$

$\displaystyle =~ \left\{128 \times \left[\cos (-\pi/3) + i\sin(-\pi/3)\right]\right\}.$